# Exit Flutter Youtube Plugin

Tags: youtube, dart, flutter

I am using [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_youtube#-readme-tab-) Flutter video Plugin. It serves my purpose and plays the video. However even when the video finishes, the video window does not auto close. Also, using rhe back button causes the app state to freeze in landscape mode. This only happens if the

```
fllscreen: true
```

is set. Is there a way to add a listener or something and auto close the video window after the video is complete. Thanks in advance.